# Making folders with mkdir and pbpaste

Tags: macos, shell, terminal

I am using terminal to create folders with the mkdir command. I know that something like

```
cat folders.txt | xargs mkdir
```

will work but I want to take what is in the clipboard and make the folders from that list.

I am currently using this:

```
pbpaste | xargs mkdir
```

The problem I am having is that it works with one line but when I use an entire list I get an error of "File name too long" with the filename looking like XXX\rXXX\rXXX\rXXX\rXXX etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have carriage returns instead of linefeeds in your clipboard. Try replacing them:

```
pbpaste | tr '\r' '\n' | xargs mkdir
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
    pbpaste | xargs -n1 mkdir
```

it will run all `mkdir` once at a time. Feel free to test to increase the integer